# Creating PyQt5 buttons in a loop: all buttons trigger the same callback

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I should mention that I've read these but I'm still unable to achieve my goal:

[[Using a dictionary in a for loop to create buttons doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189017/using-a-dictionary-in-a-for-loop-to-create-buttons-doesnt-work][1])

[[QtCore.QObject.connect in a loop only affects the last instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510860/qtcore-qobject-connect-in-a-loop-only-affects-the-last-instance][2])

My goal is to make a linux 'launcher' application. Button creation, placement, etc. is working like a charm but there's one problem - all buttons trigger the same callback - the last one to be connected in the button creation loop.

Here's a basic version of the script to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
class App(QMainWindow):

    def launch(self, filepath):
        subprocess.run(filepath)


    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()

        for btn in matrix:

            filepath = matrix[btn]['path']
            icon = matrix[btn]['setIcon']
            posx = matrix[btn]['posx']
            posy = matrix[btn]['posy']

            matrix[btn] = QToolButton(self)
            matrix[btn].setIcon(QIcon(icon))
            matrix[btn].setIconSize(QSize(64, 64))
            matrix[btn].resize(100, 100)
            matrix[btn].move(posx, posy)
            matrix[btn].clicked.connect(lambda launch: self.launch(filepath))

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(150, 150, 1250, 650)
        self.setWindowTitle('LinuxLauncher')

        self.show()


    if __name__ == '__main__':

        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = App()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I know there's an answer but I've been at it for hours - I'd appreciate it someone could help me out of this jam - Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about 'matrix' - see the comment under the answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not understand what type of structure is matrix, but I think it is equivalent to a list of dictionaries.

The problem is that you must pass as an argument to the lambda function assigning it, the clicked signal takes as a parameter a Boolean value that indicates that if the button is checked or not (by default this property is disabled so that this value is false), you must add another parameter.

```
class App(QMainWindow):
    def launch(self, filepath):
        subprocess.run(filepath)

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()

        matrix = [{"path": "path1", "setIcon": "icon1", "posx": 0, "posy": 0}, 
        {"path": "path2", "setIcon": "icon2", "posx": 0, "posy": 150},
        {"path": "path3", "setIcon": "icon3", "posx": 0, "posy": 300}]

        for value in matrix:

            filepath = value['path']
            icon =  value['setIcon']
            posx = value['posx']
            posy = value['posy']

            btn = QToolButton(self)
            btn.setIcon(QIcon(icon))
            btn.setIconSize(QSize(64, 64))
            btn.resize(100, 100)
            btn.move(posx, posy)
            btn.clicked.connect(lambda checked, arg=filepath: self.launch(arg))

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(150, 150, 1250, 650)
        self.setWindowTitle('LinuxLauncher')
        self.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it works! Sorry I didn't explain 'matrix' - it's a dictionary of dictionaries read from a yaml file and specifies which icons, where to place the buttons, etc. Excellent job, sir! I will accept your answer just as soon as I can figure out how (this is my first question ever).

Comment: @tscv11 to know how to mark an answer as correct, review the [tour]

Comment: For the record I realize you were right - the yaml data is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: how can i pass multiple arguments